# **UPDATED**: Windows 10 Laptop problems: regular small freezes, boots on BIOS and makes BSODs

Tags: windows-10, laptop, motherboard, freeze, bsod

I have this setup:

**Monitor(s):**

- Before: Double AOC 23inches Full HD, Model I2369Vm
- Now: One AOC 27inches 4K, Model U2777PQU

**Computer:** MSI GS60-2PC Ghost Laptop, *out since summer 2014*

**Computer's specifications:**

- Intel i7-4710HQ (4 cores, 4 threads)
- Intel HD 4600, discrete GPU
- 8GB of RAM
- nVidia GT860M, dedicated GPU
- Windows 10 Family, version 1803
- `C:\` M.2 120GB SSD, 25GB remaining today
- `D:\` 1TB HDD, ~190GB remaining today

**Usually running softwares:** Firefox, Spotify, Discord, Telegram. Occasionnally Overwatch, or VSCode or Affinity Designer.

---

For some time, I have been suspecting some faulty hardware on my gaming laptop. For a year now, I have been experiencing small freezes that occurs entirely randomly with any action in the OS GUI and software (`Explorer.exe`, Firefox, Spotify,...) and it drives me crazy because it even occurs when there are no displayed software that could make the `D:\` hard drive 100% spikes in the Task Manager and yet, it still happens. And it's always happening. Sometimes, when I play or do some intensive tasks this computer is supposed to be able to execute correctly, it beeps of saturation.

I already reset my OS recently, and the freezes keep coming, except one day in April when after a first BSOD when a QHD monitor (Dell UltraSharp U2715H) was plugged on it, the freezes haven't occured during 3 weeks while using a triple FHD display (laptop's + 2 externals), but it eventually came back.

Now, since I installed my new monitor less than two weeks ago, I noticed that my laptop  is even more "capricious" than previously. For instance, I cannot put it to sleep during night because it turns on 3 hours later (to go to hibernation mode) directly on the BIOS. When the laptop goes to sleep by itself after a long time of inactivity (dinner, going to buy groceries,...), the laptop goes BSOD when waking it up. It also happens when the monitor is unplugged to the computer. It also boots on BIOS/UEFI when I put it directly on hibernation. The monitor is plugged using a DisplayPort cable (which has no ThunderBolt connectivity). I haven't tried HDMI just yet. I checked boot order, and the `C:\` drive is at first position.

I checked the S.M.A.R.T. datas for my `C:\` and the `D:\` Drives with CrystalDiskInfo and both disks' health are noted as correct.

However, 3-4 weeks ago, I had to remove my battery because it has swollen and it bent the computer bottom part, but the freezes were already there back then. I don't know since when the battery was actually swollen and the computer bent, I thought my vision was deficient (and it is, I got glasses since then and that is how I noticed it was actually bent).

At this point, I am unsure what is a consequence, and what is a symptom, and I don't know where to look at, nor what to do anymore. But I suspect the motherboard to be in the end of its life.

Has anyone ever experienced this kind of problem?

---

#### Update status:

I have more informations about the BSODs:

- [`REGISTRY_FILTER_DRIVER_EXCEPTION`](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/40pvyv/bsod_from_registry_filter_driver_exception/) with `WdFilter.sys` (from Reddit)
- [`KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms854944.aspx) with `kbdclass.sys` failing would mean RAM is failing.

I did a memtest with `sfc /scannow` and the RAM seems correct too.

But this does not explain why the computer reboots on the BIOS / UEFI right away. Are the BSODs a symptom from something more concerning?

Comment: KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR is much more likely due to disk problems (or SSD problems)  than RAM problems. Particularly if there are no other indications of RAM problem.

Comment: Okay, then I don't get it: why is CrystalDiskInfo telling me both disks' health is correct ?

Comment: I don't know. But I can tell you that that error code is raised when the disk driver in Windows reports "that read operation that was just tried? It failed." It's reporting an error that came from the disk subsystem. The fault could be in the disk controller, or the drive itself, or maybe even the cable. I don't know what checks CrystalDiskInfo makes but if it's just reading the SMART info from the drive it's no guarantee of "health".

Comment: Anyway, the scrap bins are full of components that passed all kinds of diagnostics but failed in real-world use. Failing a diagnostic _probably_ means the item is bad, but passing the diagnostic doesn't mean "it's good" with anywhere near as much certainty.

Comment: Is there anything in your Windows System error log about "Disk" events?

Comment: Well I upgraded all my drivers and I have no more BSODs nor boot on BIOS which is a great thing. However, I got told to [deactivate a driver for disk performance](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/9goe8n/posted_on_superusercom_windows_10_laptop_problems/e675664/) (because it's not usually bundled with Windows) and Windows simply won't boot from now on and asking for repairs, so I guess that my last solution would be a complete OS reset now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I upgraded all my drivers and I have no more BSODs nor boot on BIOS which is a great thing. However, I got told to deactivate a driver for disk performance (because it's not usually bundled with Windows) and Windows simply won't boot from now on and asking for repairs, so I guess that my last solution would be a complete OS reset now.

I reset it completely because I could not get Windows back.